# What does "using var_name = data_type;" in C++ means?

Tags: c++, alias, using

I found a piece of code that uses the following statement:

```
using var_name = data_type;
```

This is the first time that I encountered it. What does it mean or do?

Comment: There is no such thing as "c/c++".

Comment: in c++11, it is equivalent to `typedef data_type var_name;`.

Comment: It's a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Comment: It's something that you will find explained in every good C++ book.

Comment: I don't get the 16 downvotes on this post ...

Comment: Note that `var_name` in your example is **not** a variable name.  It is a type alias.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **type alias**. Quite simply it is a way of identifying an existing data type with a new name. More like giving a synonym since it **does not** create a new data type.

```
using diameter = int;
diameter circle = 10;
```

**using** is used in C++. **typedef** which is a keyword in C can be used to do the same thing.

```
typedef unsigned int size;

typedef int* IntPtr ;
IntPtr x, y, z;
```

This could be used as an alternative to long/ complicated names of data types. And also in the 1st example if you later on want to change the diameter to float, you would just have to change the definition rather than all the places in the program.